# Laravel Mix And NPM Does Not Seem To Be Compiling Assets

Tags: php, laravel, npm, laravel-mix, laravel-10

I have installed latest version of Laravel framework and I wanted to install Bootstrap via Laravel Mix.

So I followed these steps:

```
npm install

npm install laravel-mix --save-dev

npm install bootstrap jquery --save
```

Then I created `webpack.mix.js` and added this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .copy('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'public/js/bootstrap.js')
   .copy('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'public/js/jquery.js');
```

Then I tried to compile the assets:

`npm run dev`

After that added required links to the blade:

```
<!-- head section -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- after body tag -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
```

But now the problem is those files (bootstrap.js, jquery.js and app.css) do not exist at the public directory somehow!

So how to fix this issue?